# Office Add-ins manifest Dynamic Ribbon Sign-in Icon stop working after opening multiple Excel office

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, ribbonx

We have develop Dynamic Ribbon Add-ins Manifest xml file with Sign-in and Sign-out icon by using Office.js library (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands).

After uploading manifest file from Office Add-ins, Dynamic Ribbons get populate as Sign-in enable and Sign-out disable. Then after login, Sign-in icon got disable and Sign-out gets enable.[image]

But when we open new Excel file and try to upload manifest file then previous running Excel's Dynamic Ribbon Sign-in icon stop working though its shows enable. It does not allow to open login page of application.

Please help us to find solution. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What code do you have in the ribbon callbacks?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev we are using React  and JavaScript methods in our application.

const enableButton =  () => {
    const button: Control = {id: "MyButton", enabled: true};
    const parentGroup: Group = {id: "CustomGroup111", controls: [button]};
    const parentTab: Tab = {id: "OfficeAddinTab1", groups: [parentGroup]};
    const ribbonUpdater: RibbonUpdaterData = { tabs: [parentTab]};
    Office.ribbon.requestUpdate(ribbonUpdater);
}

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev we are calling method in Manifest xml file using 
<Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">          <FunctionName>enableButton</FunctionName>
 </Action>

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev please help me solve this issue as our business is affecting. We have used below manifest tags but after logout Sign In  page is not loading again. It just open taskpane.
<Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
          <FunctionName>enableButton</FunctionName>
         </Action>
         <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
          <TaskpaneId>Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument</TaskpaneId>
          <SourceLocation resid="ContosoAddin.Url" />
         </Action>

Comment: Comments is not the right place for the code samples I think.